# How to find only first entry in dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some dom like

```
.....
   <ul>*
     <li>
       <ul>
            Sone html here
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
.....
   <ul>*
     <li>
       <ul>
         <li>
             <ul>

            Some html here
              </ul>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
......
```

How can I find the first `<ul>` elements (marked by *) using jQuery?

I used something like

```
$('body ul:first-child')
```

but this returns only one element

Comment: Are you asking how to find **only** the *top level* `ul`?

Comment: Are there and other elements between `body` and the `ul` you marked there with the asterisks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why few person recomended to delete answer bnu right answer is

```
$('ul:not(ul ul)')
```

we need to exclude ul included in ul in this case we get ul only on  top level (marked by *)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use immediate child selector to target elements that are immediate child of their parent:

```
$('body > ul')
```

Comment: But OP wnats more than just first one. See his HTML posted markup and (*)

Comment: @A.Wolff: probably immediate child selector OP is looking for.

Comment: Ya, it would be better indeed ;)

Comment: This assumes that the `ul` **are** direct children of the DOM...which they may not be. In fact, the question requires a JS solution, does it not?

Comment: @Paulie_D : that's how it looks like from what OP is doing.

Comment: There's no indication that the `ul` are direct children since we don't know the other HTML. It seemed likely to me that the OP was, in fact, trying to select just the top level `ul` which, in fact, was the case.